# Restoring exchange internet account settings on mac from Time Machine

Tags: exchange, time-machine, macos-mojave

I have a problem to connect to my employers exchange account with my Mac. For a while I have got an error message "Unable to verify account name or password" when trying to connect to the account. Propably the main reason for this is that my employer doesn't provide autodiscover servise for exchange and I should disable that in my internet account settings.

However, hoping that reconfiguration of exchange account would help I removed my exchange account before I had read about this autodiscover service. Disabling that service is done by each internet account which I now am not able to create for exchange.

So, I believe my only possibility is to recover Exchange account settings from Time machine. What files should I recover?

Answer (score 0):

On my experience, it could be achieved, you could log on the Exchange account through OWA, and verify the result.